# How to use jackc/pgx with connection pool, context, prepared statements etc

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm still not an expert in golang and still learning. This is also my first experience with postgresql

```
import "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"

const DB = "postgres://postgres:xxx@localhost:5432/mydb?pool_min_conns=1&pool_max_conns=5&pool_max_conn_idle_time=30s"

dbpool, err := pgxpool.New(context.Background(), DB)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Unable to create connection pool: "+err.Error())
}
defer dbpool.Close()
```

**1. How to get a connection from the pool and use prepared statements, where you pass the SQL and the SQL values as two separate arguments?**

Coming from PHP and have never worked with db pooling before.

**2. How to ensure when you pull a connection from the pool is "fresh" and you don't continue on a previous not completed transaction (rollback/commit)?**

**3. The same when you release a connection back to the pool. Will it automatically do a rollback if the context is cancelled or the request failed?**

**4. How make use of goroutines when requesting the database? Is it possible to make parallel select queries in the same transaction or does all queries have to be serial? I guess all write queries have to be serial?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How to get a connection from the pool and use prepared statements, where you pass the SQL and the SQL values as two separately arguments?

Generally you don't. The pool is responsible for the management of connections (acquiring and releasing) as well as the management of prepared statements (creating and caching).

If, however, you want to maintain control, then you can explicitly acquire a connection from the pool by using the [`Acquire`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.Acquire) method, or any of its related methods.

Similarly, if you want to manually create and reuse a prepared statement (e.g., you need to execute the same query within a tight loop but you don't want to rely on the pool's caching of prepared statements), then you can use the acquired connection's [`Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Conn.Conn) method which returns the [`*pgx.Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4#Conn) representation of the connection, and which has a method called [`Prepare`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4#Conn.Prepare).

> 2. How to ensure when you pull a connection from the pool is "fresh" and you don't continue on a previous not completed transaction (rollback/commit)?

The pool's Acquire methods return *available* connections. Connections that are in use, i.e. unreleased, are, by definition, not available, and will not be returned by the Acquire methods.

> 3. The same when you release a connection back to the pool. Will it automatically do a rollback if the context is cancelled or the request failed?

The resources held by a connection that's released back to the pool, if not idle, will be *destroyed*. Regarding transaction commit/rollback, neither of them will be called automatically, the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.Begin) explicitly says: *"Commit or Rollback must be called on the returned transaction to finalize the transaction block."*

> 4. How make use of goroutines when requesting the database? Is it possible to make parallel select queries in the same transaction or does all queries have to be serial? I guess all write queries have to be serial?

The pool is safe for concurrent use. However neither [`pgxpool.Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Conn) nor [`pgxpool.Tx`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Tx) are safe for concurrent use.

---

##### Example:

`Begin` does not have support for auto-rollback nor auto-commit, you yourself must, as stated by the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.Begin), call `Rollback` or `Commit` to "finalize the transaction block".

```golang
func f(ctx context.Context, pool *pgxpool.Pool) (err error) {
    tx, err := pool.Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback(ctx)
        } else {
            tx.Commit(ctx)
        }
    }()

    _, err := tx.Exec(ctx, "insert into users (email) values ($1)", "c@em.com")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var id int
    row := tx.QueryRow(ctx, "select id from users where email = $1", "c@em.com")
    if err := row.Scan(&id); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // NOTE: the above is just an example, if you need the auto
    // generated id of an inserted record, please use the RETURNING
    // clause supported by PostgreSQL.
    return nil
}
```

You can however use [`BeginFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.BeginFunc) if you want pgx to `Rollback` or `Commit` the transaction for you.

```golang
func f(ctx context.Context, pool *pgxpool.Pool) (err error) {
    return pool.BeginFunc(ctx, func(tx pgx.Tx) error {
        _, err := tx.Exec(ctx, "insert into users (email) values ($1)", "c@em.com")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var id int
        row := tx.QueryRow(ctx, "select id from users where email = $1", "c@em.com")
        if err := row.Scan(&id); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // NOTE: the above is just an example, if you need the auto
        // generated id of an inserted record, please use the RETURNING
        // clause supported by PostgreSQL.
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. If you want to use transactions with parallel queries it's correct you **can not** use the `Acquire` methods to pull out connections yourself? Can you show an example on how to use connection pool **without** `Acquire` with a `select` and an `insert` query (with prepared statements)?

Comment: *"transactions with parallel queries it's correct you can not use the Acquire methods"* -- I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `pgxpool.Tx` is __unsafe__ for concurrent use, regardless whether you've created it using `Pool.Begin` or `Conn.Begin` or whatever, i.e. regardless whether or not you've used Acquire in the process. Acquiring connections and using transactions are two very separate things.

Comment: *"Can you show an example on how to use connection pool without Acquire ..."* -- Use [`Query`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.Query) to execute queries that can return zero or more rows. Use [`QueryRow`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.QueryRow) to execute queries that can return a single row. Use [`Exec`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool#Pool.Exec)` to execute queries that do not return any rows.

Comment: @clarkk Prepared statements are _the_ mechanism to send data over to the postgresql backend alongside with the query text, therefore, whenever you're executing a query that has parameter placeholders and takes arguments, the driver will have to create a prepared statement and execute the query through that. So, by convention, drivers do prepared statements automatically and under the hood whenever you call Query, QueryRow, or Exec. And pgx also caches the prepared statements for reuse.

Comment: I don't quite understand the transaction part. When I look at `Query` it returns `(pgx.Rows, error)`.. Where is the transaction? How can I control the actual transaction with `begin`, `rollback` and `commit`?  Let's say I execute an `insert`. How can I use the same transaction to de a `select` afterwards and see the new data in the db?

Comment: Could you please show me a `select` and `insert` example where you start the transaction with `begin` and `commit` in the end? :) What if I want to execute my queries with auto-commit?`

Comment: Thanks for the examples! :) Just one last question. When using `pgxpool`. If you start multiple queries simultaneously (via goroutines) then all available connections in the pool will be used? But if you start a transaction `Begin` and you run multiple queries via goroutines only that one connection will be used?

Comment: As I've already said @clarkk, transactions, i.e. `pxpool.Tx` are __not safe for concurrent use__. If you use a single Tx in multiple goroutines your program will likely crash, and even if it doesn't, it's state will most certainly end up invalid. And, a transaction always runs in a single session (i.e. connection); a single transaction being executed through multiple connections is not a thing, at least not in postgres.